# How to get all the data using a time value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

```
mealtime_id mealtime_name   start_time  end_time
1   Breakfast   07:00:00    10:00:00    
2   Lunch   12:00:00    14:30:00    
3   Dinner  18:00:00    20:00:00
```

In the image above (or the snippet), I have columns `start_time` and `end_time`.

How to only show if the current time is `12:03:00` ?

This what I had in mind:

```
SELECT * FROM ti_mealtimes
WHERE start_time >= '12:03:00' AND end_time <= '12:03:00';
```

The expected result should be **Lunch**. Since **12:03:00** is in between *12:00:00 to  14:30:00*

```
mealtime_id mealtime_name   start_time  end_time
2   Lunch   12:00:00    14:30:00
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. (And I'm too old to read that tiny image text...)

Comment: @jarlh i have updated post with table in text.

Comment: Much better! And also show us the expected result.

Comment: "How to only show if the current time is 12:03:00" - what does that mean? Also, why did you tag this question with PHP, but not add any PHP code to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
SELECT * FROM ti_mealtimes
WHERE current_time between start_time and end_time
```

Or, perhaps, but probably not:

```
SELECT * FROM ti_mealtimes
WHERE '12:03:00' between start_time and end_time
```

Comment: The latter works.

`
SELECT * FROM ti_mealtimes
WHERE '12:03:00' between start_time and end_time
`

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE statement is conflicted. You are telling it to pull records where start_time is at least 12:03:00 and pull records where end_time is no older than 12:03:00

Have you tried BETWEEN?

```
SELECT
     [mealtime_name]
FROM
     [tbl_name] 
WHERE
     [time] BETWEEN [start_time] AND [end_time]
```

This should pull the row where [time] is between the two column limits, inclusively.

Comment: The OP states "The expected result should be Lunch. Since 12:03:00 is in between 12:00:00 to 14:30:00"

Looking back at it, the OP's initial statement would have probably worked if they flipped the signs (i.e. start_time <= time_value and end_time >= time_value)

Comment: This also works. Your answer is similar to @jarlh.